# ASP.NET Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParseErrorException

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, telerik

I'm working on a project left by a programmer in our company

i'd like to know what could be the reasons im getting this error

[image]

this is always firing during the execution of this line

```
Response.Redirect("ViewPositions.aspx?empid=1");
```

but the thing is, the ViewPositions.aspx is working ok when i navigate it from the addressbar
and not coming from the `Response.Redirect`

on the other hand the form where in the Response.Redirect was called, have a complicated layout.

its a registration wizard for an account. And it has RadPageView, RadMultiPage, RadAjaxPanel,RadAjaxLoadingPanel,RadAsyncUpload, some DropDownBoxes, some TextBoxes and GridView.

everything is working and updating the database but when it comes to the redirection... its giving the error i've posted.

Note: there are no Response.Write calls in both pages

The question is.

I would like to know what are the possible causes of this error. Because its hard to debug.

I've googled this problem and tried the solutions but no luck.

Just point me please to the right direction.

Thank you.

**Update: Ive confirmed that everything works fine.. just the Response.Redirect is triggering this problem.. please let me know if i need to post anything more.**

**Update: I tried changing the redirect to... Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
and it throws a different error**

[image]

*which means it is certain that the page calling the redirect is causing the error..
my confusion is.. the page is working fine when its not calling any redirect... please help =(*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using telerik/rad controls, it has httpModules especialy for UpdatePanel

Tell me if it solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that further page processing is happening after your Response.Redirect?  Have you tried:

```
Response.Redirect("ViewPositions.aspx?empid=1", true)
```

to end the execution of the current page?

Comment: actually i tried that also too.. and it didn't work thanks though